# Character encoding while reading data using Java-JDBC from Oracle database

Tags: java, encoding, jdbc, utf-8, oracle10g

We have data stored in oracle 10g db which contains french character set. The requirement is to read the data and generate a output file using Java.

I checked the validity of the data in Oracle db via SQL*plus and it looks good.

From windows:

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN.AL32UTF8
sqlplus scott/tiger
sql>  select billing_address from MYTABLE t where ADDRESS_ID=1 ;
billing_address
-----------------------
MONTRÉAL QUÉ
```

Now when I read the table from Java to generate a output file, the character is all garbled and I see question marks in place of É.

Is there any special encoding that I need to set when I try to read/write the data in Java.

Am using the `ojdbc14.jar` and setting the encoding as UTF-8.

---

**Update**: Here's my java code snippet.

```
        Charset cs1 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from talbe where address_id=1");
        ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        Writer w = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        if(rs.next()) {

            String billingaddress = rs.getString("BILLING_ADDRESS");

            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myout.dat"));
            w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos,cs1));
            w.write(billingaddress);
        }
```

Comment: Did you think about encoding the data when writing it to the output file?

Comment: Attached herewith snippet of my java code.
Charset cs1 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from table where address_id=1");
ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
Writer w = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
if(rs.next()) {
  String billingaddress = rs.getString("BILLING_ADDRESS");
  fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myout.dat"));
  w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos,cs1));
  w.write(billingaddress);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the initial charset that was set while loading the data into the oracle database. we changed the charset in the sql*loader control file and it works fine now.

Comment: which charset did you changed to, our charset is AL16UTF16 is it ok?

Comment: @raghavan can you please provide the exact file details that you changed ?

Comment: @Raghavan 8 years later, and I too would like to know the answer to arjun 's and nikli 's question

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things to check...

1. Your jdbc url should have **`?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8`** in it somewhere
2. Your JVM should have all the different char-sets installed that you need
3. Maybe something is happening in the code to write to file/read from file

   - Can you post some of your java code if your problem still persists?

Comment: Point 1 is MySQL JDBC driver specific. He's using Oracle. It's however a good direction to look the cause for.