# How to insert Thai language in Oracle using Java bytes?

Tags: java, oracle

```
Connection con = null;
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe";
String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
String s = "สวัสดี";
System.out.println("Thai hello :" + s);
String temp = s.getBytes() + "";
String temp2 = new String(s.getBytes());
System.out.println("Thai temp bytes :" + temp);
System.out.println("Thai temp2 bytes :" + temp2);
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "xxxxx");

    try {
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into encodeleo VALUES(?)");
        st.setBytes(1, s.getBytes());
        st.executeUpdate();
        String temp1;
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name from encodeleo");
        rs.next();
        temp1 = new String(rs.getBytes("name"));
        System.out.println("temp1 :" + temp1);
        System.out.println("1 row affected");
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried using UTF-8, but I couldn't encode and decode other languages in Java.

Could please give me some idea also about how to use UTF-8 to encode the
string, insert into Oracle and get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle DB has ability to store multi-languages in its tables.We have to choose the right character set for this purpose.

You may facing problem due to:

> 1. The NLS configuration of the client, who entering the data was not properly configured.
> 2. The NLS configuration of the client, who retrieving the data is not properly configured.

One Thai character in the Thai character set requires 3 bytes in UTF8 or AL32UTF8.

and this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378724/character-encoding-while-reading-data-using-java-jdbc-from-oracle-database) will help you.

```
NLS_LANG=THAI_THAILAND.TH8TISASCII;
```

For More Information [Oracle Supported Locales](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/locale.doc.html)
and [Internationalization in Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/#retrieving)